# Anwers converted to comments

Tags: discussion

I have been trying to help by answering some people problems.
Why are some of my answers to people post converted to comments?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pasting a link and saying "Have you tried this" is **not** an answer.

---

https://askubuntu.com/questions/547267/trouble-running-executable-files-on-ubuntu/547272#comment749829_547267 < not an answer

https://askubuntu.com/questions/547267/trouble-running-executable-files-on-ubuntu/547272#comment749830_547272 < not an answer

https://askubuntu.com/questions/443192/huawei-usb-stick-ec169-not-connecting-on-ubuntu-10-10#comment749810_443192 < not an answer, If you find a question that seems duplicated use the "flag" to indicate that a question may have a duplicate on the question you find.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/523801/mts-mblaze-huawei-ec-315-ubuntu-14-04#comment749818_523801 < same with this

https://askubuntu.com/a/547272/47291 < closer, but still not an answer, or an extremely bad one...

[Is it yet possible to use Facebook video chat without a VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52054/is-it-yet-possible-to-use-facebook-video-chat-without-a-vm#comment749289_52054) < not an answer, not even close

https://askubuntu.com/a/547274/47291 < "Maybe this will help"? No... it probably won't if the user doesn’t even know how.

---

To sum it up, Answers are resevered for Complete answers - Not just a link, not asking for clarification either.

---

If you are unclear on what an "Answer" is, take a look around the site and see which answers get upvotes:

https://askubuntu.com/a/40351/47291

https://askubuntu.com/a/7484/47291

https://askubuntu.com/a/40781/47291

https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/47291

So, what do these have in common?
Some things that help:

- Screenshots
- Step by step instructions
- Supplemtry links (note that all the information needed to solve is in the post, only used as sources, or *further reading*)

---

https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer A good place to start

and in the "it is not an answer" flag description:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
>   question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether.

Comment: thank you very much... i will start by correcting those

Comment: Nevertheless I will be banned but at least I made things right.
and when I create my knew account i won't be doing the same mistakes.
thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This keeps getting worst. XDDD

I did some mistakes but I have also spent a lot of time correcting them.

What I got was more negatives votes and getting banned in the worst way possible XDDD

Comment: It is nice to see this type of encouragement

Comment: Well next account XDDDDD
I really ca not understand how 2 bad posts got me kicked out but ok.